# printing vector elements error message

Tags: c++, vector

I'm a beginner in c++. The following simple program to push elements into vector and to display them while traversing, is not working correctly. Compiler says "Expression:vector iterator is not derrencable."
Can any one help me about this ??

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include<vector>
    int main()
    {
    int n;
    std::vector<int>x;
    std::vector<int>::iterator it;
    for (it = x.begin(); it != x.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout << "enter an element in the vector:" << "\n";
        std::cin >> n;
        x.push_back(n);
        std::cout << "vector:" << "\n";
        std::cout << *it;
    }

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: To begin with you need *two* loops: One to enter data and one to print the data.

Comment: As for your problem, please copy-paste the *actual* error, in full and unedited, into the body of the question. And then point out where in the source you get the error (for example by a comment).

Comment: push_back() can invalidate iterators. Two loops as Joachim suggests.

Comment: I don't get any error when I run this program. In fact, I don't see how the loop could ever be entered because the loop condition is initially false.

Answer (score 0):

Two iterators are choosen, i.e, it1 and it2 variables. 
it1 is used for storing input into the vector. Initial input of the vector is stored here.

```
std::vector<int>::iterator it1;
it1=x.begin();
std::cout << "enter an element in the vector: " << "\n";
std::cin >> n;
x.push_back(n);
```

To quit the loop, enter '-1'

```
while(n!=-1)
{
++it1;
std::cout << "enter an element in the vector: " << "\n";
std::cin >> n;
x.push_back(n);
} ;
```

it2 for displaying output from the vector.

```
for(it2 = x.begin(); it2 != x.end(); ++it2)
  std::cout<<*it2<<" ";//no need of curly braces for single for statement
```

'
Complete working program :

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>

int main()
{
  int n;
  std::vector<int> x;
  std::vector<int>::iterator it1;
  std::vector<int>::iterator it2;
  it1=x.begin();
  std::cout << "enter an element in the vector: " << "\n";
  std::cin >> n;
  x.push_back(n);

  while(n!=-1)
  {
    ++it1;
    std::cout << "enter an element in the vector: " << "\n";
    std::cin >> n;
    x.push_back(n);
  };

  std::cout<<"Vector : ";
  for(it2 = x.begin(); it2 != x.end(); ++it2)
    std::cout<<*it2<<" " ;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Two loops , one for each iterator are made. Initial condition is set in the first loop of it1. i.e, it1=x.begin() and while(n!=-1)

Comment: _Using 'std' as namespace saves much effort in repeating "std::"_ Please don't advise people to do this.

Comment: i tried with two loops but i'm still having this error message

Comment: What is the use of it1 here ? You are pushing back elements so I don't see its use. Also, When you type -1 to leave the input loop, it will also push back -1 inside the vector, which is not I think the wanted behaviour